# how get  treenodes in treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

c#. Windows gui forms.

How can i get treenodes in the treeview? And what eventhandler i should use to show smth when i clicked on the treeview some nodes ? 
p.s sory for bad english

Comment: What do you mean by "tend to treenodes" ? Try also with google translate if you will...

Comment: i meant how can i know about all treenodes in reeview and treenodes ine each treenode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the [FirstNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.firstnode.aspx) and [NextNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.nextnode.aspx) properties. `FirstNode` gives you the first child of a particular node. `NextNode` gives you the next sibling.  So, given this tree structure:

```
Database1
  Table1
  Table2
  Table3
Database2
  TableX
  TableY
```

If you're on the `Database` node, then `FirstNode` is a reference to `Table1`, and `NextNode` is a reference to `Database2`.

Comment: if there is no child or next sibling the result will be null ?

Comment: That is correct. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.firstnode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

*How can i get treenodes in the treeview?*

Use the SelectedNode property of the Treeview
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.selectednode.aspx

*what eventhandler i should use to show smth when i clicked on the treeview some nodes ?*

Use the AfterSelect event of the TreeView.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.afterselect.aspx